# Unix Bash - Copy files from a source folder recursively to destination/*file_extension*(ex. “txt”) folder

Tags: bash, shell, unix, recursion

This is my code, something in the rec_copy() function isn't working properly, probably this line:

> cp $1/$f $HOME/$2/$dest

The extension named folders are created in the destination folder but the files are not copied there. Can you help me?

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
        echo "Usage: $0 <source> <destination>"
        exit
fi

if [ ! -d $1 ]
then
        echo "Source folder does not exist"
        exit
fi

if [ -d $2 ]
then
        rm -r $2
        mkdir $2
else
        mkdir $2
fi

extension=`ls -l $1 | grep -v "^d" | awk '{ print $10; }' | sed 's/^.*\.//g'`
for f in $extension
do
        if [ ! -d $1/$f ]
        then
                mkdir $2/$f
        fi
done

rec_copy(){
folder=`ls $1`
for f in $folder
do
        dest=`echo "$f" | sed 's/.*\.//g'`
        if [ -f $1/$f ]
        then
                cp $1/$f $HOME/$2/$dest
        elif [ -d $1/$f ]
        then
                rec_copy $1/$f
        fi
done
}

rec_copy $1
```

Comment: try use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check your code first, maybe you can fix the error by it

Comment: @YuJiaao no errors just warnings

Comment: Start quoting variables.

Comment: @Cyrus I tried it both ways, same result, my copying is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in case someone ever needs it:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
        echo "Usage: $0 <izvor> <destinacija>"
        exit
fi

if [ ! -d "$1" ]
then
        echo "Izvorniot folder ne postoi"
        exit
fi

if [ -d "$2" ]
then
        rm -r "$2"
        mkdir "$2"
else
        mkdir "$2"
fi

extension=`ls -l "$1" | grep -v "^d" | awk '{ print $10; }' | sed 's/^.*\.//g' | sort -u`
for f in $extension
do
        if [ ! -d "$1/$f" ]
        then
                mkdir "$2/$f"
        fi
done

rec_copy(){
folder=`ls "$1"`
for f in $folder
do
        dest=`echo "$f" | sed 's/.*\.//g'`
        to=`cp "$1/$f" "$2/$dest"`

        if [ -f "$1/$f" ]
        then
                echo "$to"
        elif [ -d "$1/$f" ]
        then
                rec_copy "$1/$f" "$2"
        fi
done
}

rec_copy "./$1" "./$2"
```